# If you do something that takes you out of the pale of Islam, do you have to say the shahada?

Tags: kufr, shahada

If you do a Kufr (heresy) or shirk act without knowing it, do you have to say the Shahada, if you do it knowingly, without wanting to leave Islam, do you have to as well? If you do it unknowingly but wanted to leave Islam, do you have to, and of you did it knowingly and wanted to leave Islam, do you have to say the Shahada again?

Comment: I did not understand the meaning of this: "If you do it unknownlingly but wanted to leave Islam." I mean, how can you do something knowingly, yet be deliberate about it?

Comment: If you want to leave Islam anyway, what's the point of worrying about reciting the shahaadah? It's like wanting to commit suicide but making sure that the poison is made from halaal ingredients :)

Comment: If you say or do something wrong like kufr or shirk unknowingly and you later realize it, it's better to do taubah and hope for Allah's forgiveness. And yes, recite the shahaadah again. It's better.

Answer (score 1):

Saying Shahadah would be necessary in the case that want to choose your religion as Islam. Of course you say Shahada in your Salahs everyday, namely:

> اَشْهَدُ اَنْ لااِلهَ اِلاّ اللهُ وَحْدَهُ لاشَريكَ لَهُ وَ اَشْهَدُ
>   اَنَّ مُحَمّداً عَبْدُهُ وَ رَسولُهُ.

**But if you really did a Kufr as an practice which made you as a Kafir, then you ought to say Shahadah as well.**

In truth, doing that (Kufr) knowingly or unknowingly would be so significant in the result of that. Actually it doesn't seem to be necessary in the case of Unknowing ... / But in the case of knowingly seems to be necessary for you to ... Since in fact you have leave Islam, then you ought to enter it again!

And Allah knows best

Answer (score 1):

> If you do a Kufr (heresy) or shirk act without knowing it, do you have to say the Shahada, if you do it knowingly, without wanting to leave Islam, do you have to as well?

In both cases you do not need to. You are still a Muslim who sinned and asking Allah for forgiveness + repenting should be sufficient.

> If you do it unknownlingly but wanted to leave Islam, do you have to, and of you did it knowingly and wanted to leave Islam, do you have to say the Shahada again?

If you voluntarily left Islam, then you need to believe in the Shahada to enter back. Also note that the shahada is not something that is said, but believed in. It is Sunnah to say it in front of others so you have witnesses to you entering Islam, but believing in it is the only thing required.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, your question doesn't make sense.

Secondly, you have to say the Shahadah all the time anyways. Everyday you should remember who your creator is. For example when you wake up and you are washing your face you should recite the Shahadah.

Thirdly, how can you leave Islam unknowingly? To be a Muslim you should believe in the Shahadah from the heart. Just because you have committed a major sin does not mean you are not Muslim anymore. You should repent and ask for forgiveness.